# Exception on 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, 2d

I need some help here. I'm trying to let the user to create the infrastructure if the user give the correct name from the list of infrastructure that is already been there and give use the value inside. But then I got this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
TownObject is the abstract class with infrastructure inside.
What may cause the error on the runtime? Thanks in advance.

```
townObject commtowers = new infrastructure("telekom", "communication towers", 50);
townObject busstop = new infrastructure("litatrek", "bus stop", 30);

    townObject[][] ton = new townObject[20][20];

    String iname;

    System.out.println("Enter infrastructure name : ");            
    iname = sc.nextLine();
    sc.nextLine();

    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < columns; j++){
        ****if (iname.equalsIgnoreCase(ton[i][j].getName())
            {
                ton[x][y] = new infrastructure(infName, infType, infCost);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Infrastructure is not found.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `Objects` in Java is `null`. This applys also to elements of an `Object` array.

While the array `ton` itself is instantiated, its individual elements are still `null` and need to be assigned. You need to to instantiate the elements of the array prior to invoking any operations on them:

```
for (int i=0; i < ton.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < ton[i].length; j++) {
        ton[i][j] = new townObject();
        ton[i][j].setName(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already assigned them inside as I declared it when the program start. What I'm trying to do is linking the object created inside the 2D array. Is that possible? And btw, I'm also trying to print the value of the 2D array. Do you know the way to print it so that when user enter the i and j on ton[i][j] it will print the value of them.

Comment: First fix the `NPE` issue. There is not information provided to locate the source of the exception. The stacktrace will tell you there the `NPE` is being thrown.

Comment: the NPE issue is at the **** line, it's the part where I don't know how to fix. And for the printing is for the other part of the code that is already working, but I have no idea how to print it out.

Comment: Post the stacktrace and the `infrastructure` class

Comment: thanks i just solve it . But do u know hw to print the object inside the 2d array using the coordinate given by the user ?

Comment: @ChuaYeeYin Add a `toString()` method in your `townObject` class and then call it `ton[x][y].toString()`.